Как сделать HDD с несколькими загрузочными дисками?
Я хочу, чтобы у меня был 1 hdd с несколькими установочными дисками. Разделил его на тома

Скачал 1 исошник 
Попытался сделать в Rufus, однако он разделенные логические тома видит, как 1 диск.

А я хочу, чтобы в каждом логическом томе был свой установщик операционки какой-то.

Поставьте Ventoy и не мучайтесь

@andreymal а как воспользоваться? По описанию я должен весь диск снова объединить в 1 том, после чего закинуть на него все исошники, установить Ventoy. А что дальше? Как будет работать?

делаете 1 раздел, на него ставите grub(по идее и без него можно монтировать образ прямо baremetal но не уверен), туда же закидываете все образы и конфиг для груба, в конфиге пути к iso образам и в принципе всё(конкретнее не скажу, ибо именно так не пробовал). и кстати, дробить накопитель по разделу на каждый образ, в целом так себе затея. если у вас устаревшая винда(7 или старее), скорее всего там разметка MBR(у которой лимит 4 раздела на физ. накопитель максимум). впрочем свежая версия винды не гарант того что и тип разметки свежий, 10ка вполне может встать и на MBR.

После установки вентоя и закидывания iso - просто грузишься с винта и начинает всё работать через магию.
